# Laravel routing

Tags: laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 app, I have a route:

`Route::get('admin/login', array('as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogin'));`

If I want the URL `/login` to be routed to `admin/login` can I put in a redirect, or should I basically be moving my `AuthController` up one level, i.e. out of the /admin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirect would work.
Do you mean something like...

```
Route::get('admin/login' array('as' => 'admin.login', ...);

Route::get('login', function() {
    return Redirect::route('admin.login');
});
```

Comment: Yep, that would work - thanks. I'd be interested to know if you think I need to store my admin controllers in an /admin folder or not. Is this good practice or personal preference? Are there any performance considerations?

Comment: Personally I think it's more personal preference. I don't know if there's a specific convention for this; I'd imagine if you had a number of controllers attached to the same "module" (Admin\AuthController, Admin\PostController) you'd probably want to logically group them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the '/admin/login' url when you reach the '/login' url, you have to use a redirect I think. Otherwise, add another route routed to your the method AuthController@getLogin.

Bye